# How i Can increase Height of cell A1:H1 in php excel

Tags: php, html, css, excel, codeigniter

I am using phpexcel in codeigniter and i want to print logo on first column but however i cant set cell height for that particuar merged column from A1 To H1

i tried following way but i cant get solution

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('A1')->setRowHeight(300);
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath('./images/multiply.png');
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:H1');
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('A1')->setRowHeight(300);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setHeight(100);
$objDrawing->setWidth(100);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($this->excel->getActiveSheet());
```

Please Suggest Me Any way to do it

**This Is what showing by this Code**
[image: This Is what showing by this Code]

**But I Want Like this**
[image: But I Want Like this]

Comment: You can't increase the height of an individual cell, only of a row, as shown in @onegun 's answer: what would you expect to happen to all the cells around if you changed the height of a single cell..... and would MS Excel itself allow you to do this? If MS Excel doesn't allow it, there's probably a very good reason for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just happens to do one recently, you can get the idea from

```
$column='A';
$row=2;
$excel = new PHPExcel();
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($row)->setRowHeight(200);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($column)->setWidth(50);
```

Comment: sorry , but i want to increase height of cell